# Deprecated implicitely-declared copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, type-traits, static-assert

I am trying to wrap my head around a weird characteristic of implicitely-declared copy constructors. Take the following example. Once the user implements a custom destructor, the copy-constructor isn't trivial anymore, but is still generated.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

struct test {
    test() = default;
    ~test() {
    }
    test(const test&) = default;
    int i{42};
};
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<test>, "werks"); // OK
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<test>, "sad"); // FAILS

int main() {
    test t;
    test t2(t);
    printf("%d\n", t2.i);
    return 0;
}
```

Online version : https://godbolt.org/z/t-8_W3

My understanding of trivial constructors is they are generated by the compiler. However, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) states :

> The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is
>   deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor or user-defined copy
>   assignment operator.

So, it seems there is one more state an implicitly-declared constructor can be in, which is "deprecated". It is not "trivial" and not user implemented, but still generated by your compiler... Is that correct? Does someone know a type trait or workaround to verify if a constructor is "deprecated"?

Comment: "deprecated" means it still happens, but is discouraged for your program to rely on it, and may be removed in a future standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is_trivially_copy_constructible<T>` also requires that `T` be trivially destructible. What this trait checks is if the hypothetical variable definition:

```
T t(declval<T const&>());
```

would invoke no non-trivial operations. But `test` is not trivially destructible, and that destruction is implicit in that construction.

If you change `~test() { }` to `~test() = default`, the assertion will no longer trigger.

---

The note about deprecation of implicitly defined constructor is irrelevant, as you have an explicitly defaulted copy constructor.

Comment: This is the paragraph you are referring to? "In many implementations, is_nothrow_copy_constructible also checks if the destructor throws because it is effectively noexcept(T(arg)). Same applies to is_trivially_copy_constructible, which, in these implementations, also requires that the destructor is trivial: GCC bug 51452 LWG issue 2116." So it is a bug?

Comment: Because I thought "trivial" meant generated by the compiler. In the example, it is generated by your compiler. So should be trivial.

Comment: @scx "trivial" and "generated by the compiler" do not mean the same thing at all. "trivial" has a very specific meaning in C++. Consider `struct S { std::string m; };` This class has a copy constructor and destructor generated by the compiler, neither are trivial.

Comment: That's manager-speak for "its a bug" :D Anyhow, thanks for the help!